# Changing height of floated element and broken grid layout

Tags: html, css

I need a simple solution to this [problem](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVpBzz), where floated layout is broken
when height of one element has changed. In example :hover event triggers additional element (table) appearence.

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
      <main>
        <article class="main">
            <div class="zaglushka square">
              <figure><img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/200/" alt="Заглушка 15x15">
                <figcaption>
                  <h4>15x15</h4>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>&lt;100шт</th>
                      <th>&lt;500шт</th>
                      <th>&gt;500шт</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>2₽</td>
                      <td>1.8₽</td>
                      <td>дог.</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </figcaption>
              </figure>
            </div>
            ...
            <div class="zaglushka square">
              <figure><img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/200/200/" alt="Заглушка 15x15">
                <figcaption>
                  <h4>15x15</h4>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <th>&lt;100шт</th>
                      <th>&lt;500шт</th>
                      <th>&gt;500шт</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>2₽</td>
                      <td>1.8₽</td>
                      <td>дог.</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </figcaption>
              </figure>
            </div>
        </article>
      </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 .5rem;
}

.zaglushka {
  padding: .75rem;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.zaglushka table {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.zaglushka:hover {
  z-index: 10;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
.zaglushka:hover table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
}

section.catalog figure img {
  width: 90%;
}
```

What is the simplest solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is **not using floats** because float is not for layouts, is to floating elements. Using floats in layouts causes weirds behaviours and break layouts. You should change float by inline-block element:

```
.zaglushka {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

See it working:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mePRbj

### Edit

To prevent bottom rows to move you should play with margins, in this case, on hovering the box you need to write margin -20% because you are scaling to a +20% and by this mode you avoid the margin.

```
.zaglushka:hover {
   margin: -20% 0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mePRbj

Comment: Height of rows should be consistent, top rows must overlap bottom rows. How to do that?

Comment: It makes playing with margins. In this case, you are incrementing the size of the box in a 20% (`scale(1.2)`), so applying margin `-20%` top and bottom you achieve it. See it working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mePRbj . I edit my answer with the update.

Comment: Thank you. Still have one problem when single remaining element on the last row is not displayed correctly (on :hover). http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbWLWO

Comment: I think it's because it doesn't fit. You need 5 elements per row because you define a 20% of width. So inline-block elements don't avoid whitespace. To solve this problem you must define `font-size:0` in parent container and then redefine in the childrens with a default font size (example 16px). You can see it working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYMNpm

Comment: It's weird, because if you add more elements it doesn't break. I will investigate more. If you achieve something, please, tell me how.

Comment: Inline blocks have somewhat issues with negative margin on top. If I change problem line to `margin: 0 0 -20% 0;` it is working. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avNpgK

Comment: Yeah, you only apply it to margin-bottom. I didn't know if you wanted it and it's because I write to margin-bottom and margin-top, but if you like the result is a good and clean solution!! So the complete solution is remove float, add inline-block and margin-bottom -20%. Congratulations ! :)

Comment: Not quite the end. Now. The following block is jumping up when 6th element hovered. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYMvoL